# Variables used in definitions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory, logic

Does the scope of definitions mean that a variable appearing in an expression is different to another occurrence of the same symbol later in a proof?

If I define.. let $f(x,y)=xy$ is $x$ a sort of dummy variable in this case?

If I later use a variable $x$ in an expression later is it different from the first? Is anything I say after the definition true of the variable  used in the definition?

When we define sets we seem to ignore things previously defined about the variable we previously called $x$ if we use the symbol $x$ again, is this another example where $x$ is formally different than it was before?

If this is the case, how do we differ between different variables, is it purely contextual?

Here are my other issues with this:

[What is the scope of a variable in set-building notation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4535530/what-is-the-scope-of-a-variable-in-set-building-notation)

[Should we always introduce new variables to define sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4535914/should-we-always-introduce-new-variables-to-define-sets)

[Can a variable have both 'free' and 'bound' occurences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536240/can-a-variable-have-both-free-and-bound-occurences)

Also if we have a 'bound' variable can it be 're-used' is it the same or a different variable with the same symbol?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are asking. Can you give a specific example? And a dummy variable is basically a variable that appears in a calculation/proof only has a placeholder that would've disappeared in the final result.

Comment: You might want to mention and link-to your previous questions in this area. This can provide useful context, and it may help others avoid repeating responses you've seen before. Good luck!

Comment: See [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4535914/should-we-always-introduce-new-variables-to-define-sets).

Comment: Not very clear... Assuming that the RHS is *product* (of two numbers) you are defining a new symbol $f$ for it. The use of the above definition (with the equality symbol) is that we can use substitution for equality rule to replace in a context every occurrence of $x \cdot y$ with $f(x,y)$. This means that if we have some expression (formula) with e.g. $2 \cdot 3$, we may replace it with $f(2,3)$.

Comment: Having said that, YES the variables $x$ and $y$ used in the definition are "local".

Comment: @Blue will do that.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA if I use a variable in a definition it is 'local', is this true for all bound variables? When do we draw the distinction between the variables? When it's used as a bound variable, using the same symbol free is 'different' from the first?

Comment: See comments to [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4535914/should-we-always-introduce-new-variables-to-define-sets): yes, the bound variable in $\forall x Px$ is not a "variable" at all, that is it is not a "place-holder" waiting to be filled with an input values.

Comment: And yes (see another [previous post of you](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536240/can-a-variable-have-both-free-and-bound-occurences)) a variable can have both free and bound occurrences in the same formula.

Comment: So they can be 'free' and 'bound' occurrences, but in the case of a definition it is bound and 'local'? So a re-use in this case is a new 'variable' because we are out of the scope of the previous one?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to treat natural-language math exposition as strictly as you would a programming language, which may not be possible or useful. Remember that the goal of mathematical writing is to communicate clearly with other humans. Are there cases where these variable scoping questions prevent you from understanding the author's intent?

Comment: @Karl well when I first see things like $(x,y)$ I assume things being said about $x$ and $y$ still hold from before, but you have a point.